# Uploading and Downloading Files with Django and Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm currently trying to upload some files using Django and it seems to be working for the most part. I'm at least able to see that the file is added to the specific model in the Django admin panel but I'm unable to open it. Additionally, whenever I try to get the URL of the file, I get forwarded to the Django error page with a nice error that says, `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/some_file.csv'`

Here is my file model :

```
class File(models.Model):
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    file = models.FileField(default="", upload_to="media/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.challenge.challenge_id
```

Settings.py :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'server', 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

Upload Function :

```
def uploadChallengeFile(request):
    latestChallenge = Challenge.objects.last()
    for file in request.FILES.items():
        file_model = File(challenge=latestChallenge, file=file[0])
        file_model.save()

    data = {"data": [True]}
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Download Function :

```
def downloadFile(request, challenge_id):
    challenge = Challenge.objects.filter(challenge_id=challenge_id)
    filename = File.objects.filter(challenge=challenge).values("file")[0]["file"]
    content = open(File.objects.get(challenge=challenge).file.url).read()

    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

    return response
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^api/start/download/(?P<challenge_id>[\w.@+-]+)/$', views.backendServices.downloadFile, name="download")
```

It seems like Django is saving the instance of the file but not actually storing it. Do I need to configure the `nginx.conf` to serve the files from the `/media` directory or do something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you have to configure nginx to proxy pass requests to media/ and static/ to your django instances:

The following assumes your django service can be reached at http://django:8000, but more likely if you're not using docker (and it's not named django), it would be http://localhost:8000

```
    location /static {
        proxy_pass        http://django:8000;
        proxy_redirect    default;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /media {
        proxy_pass        http://django:8000;
        proxy_redirect    default;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

Also, make sure when running in DEBUG mode (normally local dev) set the URL routes so django handles them

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.views.static import serve
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but for some reason this didn't work. Also for clarification, I am using Docker.

Comment: Can you paste your Dockerfile for nginx - and the nginx conf file as well

Comment: @undefined1010101 - see my additional comment re: changes to your urls.py file